# Comparative Mythology: What stories have very clear similarities?

Tags: comparative

I was wondering if anyone knows of two stories/gods/creatures/etc in mythology that have very distinct similarities/connections when compared with each other? I want to make a list or a chart with all the similarities. Any contribution would be helpful!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Mythology SE. Stack Exchange is a Q&A site, where users vote on the best and most useful answers. We try to avoid "list" questions because you aren't going to get a "best" answer in a list; they are all valid responses.

Comment: I think it has been done. See Aarne-Thompson-Uther Classification of Folk Tales. http://www.mftd.org/index.php?action=atu. Looks to be 2399 pages long. Almost every tale has some or many similarities with other tales. See aslo Johannes Bolte's Anmerkungungen to the Grimms KHM Märchen. He lists similar tales from through out the world to most of the KHM texts.Sometimes there are 50 or 100 or more with different similarities.

Answer (score 2):

[Flood myths](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_flood_myths) shows up frequently.

> The anthropologist Sir James Frazer compared ... "dying god" myths in his multi-volume work The Golden Bough.
>
> Vedic India, ancient China, Mayans, Incas and the ancient Germans all had myths featuring a "Cosmic Tree" whose branches reach heaven and whose roots reach hell.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparative_mythology

> untold numbers of people began to write books, papers, and dissertations on the parallels between Jesus and Osiris

http://www.eoht.info/m/page/Comparative+religion+and+mythology